# watchOS 2 beta から watchOS 2 にアップデートするにはどうすればいいですか

Tags: ios, watchkit

watchOS 2 beta を Apple Watch に入れていますが、
配信開始された watchOS 2 にアップデートしようと思い、
iPhone の Watch アプリケーションの中から
「ソフトウェア・アップデート」に進んだ所、
ソフトウェアは最新 と表示され、アップデートすることが出来ません。
どのようにアップデートを行えばいいですか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[私のポートフォリオ的な Web サイトの記事](http://s.treastrain.jp/1FpFnFp)からテキスト文書のみを抜粋したものになります。
iPhone のスクリーンショット付きで見たいという方は[そちら](http://s.treastrain.jp/1FpFnFp)を閲覧することをお勧めします。

### ① iOS 9.0 以降にアップデートする。

まず、iPhone を iOS 9.0 以降にアップデートしてください。
[iOS 9 へのアップデート方法はこちらの記事](http://s.treastrain.jp/1UUHnXQ)で紹介しています。

### ② Watch アプリを開く

iPhone の Watch アプリケーションを開きます。

### ③ 一般をタップ

### ④ プロファイル をタップ

### ⑤ watchOS 2 beta をタップ

### ⑥ プロファイルを削除 をタップ

### ⑦ iPhone のパスコードを入力する

### ⑧ 削除 をタップ

### ⑨ プロファイルが削除されたことを確認する

プロファイルを削除中 という画面の後、
「現在インストールされているプロファイルがありません」と
表示されます。

### ⑩ 通常のアップデートに進む

プロファイルの削除が完了すると、
通常のアップデートの手順と同じように
「ソフトウェア・アップデート」から
watchOS 2 にアップデートすることが出来ます。